# NSViewで描画しているOpenGLの背景を透明にしたい

Tags: c#, macos, opengl

Mac上で、OpenTKを利用して、描画を行おうとしています。

サンプルを元に、背景を透明にしようとしているのですが、黒のまま変化が見られない状況です。
以下が、そのコードです。

```
        gameWindow = new MonoMacGameView( new CoreGraphics.CGRect(x,y,width,height) );
       // Wire-up any required Game events
        gameWindow.Load += (sender, e) =>
        {
            // TODO: Initialize settings, load textures and sounds here
        };

        gameWindow.Resize += (sender, e) =>
        {
            // Adjust the GL view to be the same size as the window
            GL.Viewport(0, 0, gameWindow.Size.Width, gameWindow.Size.Height);
        };

        gameWindow.UpdateFrame += (sender, e) =>
        {
            // TODO: Add any game logic or physics
        };

        gameWindow.RenderFrame += (sender, e) =>
        {
            GL.Enable( EnableCap.AlphaTest );
            GL.Enable( EnableCap.Blend );

            GL.ClearColor( 0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f );

            // Setup buffer
            GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

            GL.PushMatrix();

            GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);

            // Draw a simple triangle
            GL.LoadIdentity();
            GL.Ortho(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 4.0);
            GL.Begin(BeginMode.Triangles);
            GL.Color3(Color.MidnightBlue);
            GL.Vertex2(-1.0f, 1.0f);
            GL.Color3(Color.SpringGreen);
            GL.Vertex2(0.0f, -1.0f);
            //GL.Color3(Color.Ivory);
            GL.Color4( 0.0f,0.5f,0.5f,0.1f);
            GL.Vertex2(1.0f, 1.0f);
            GL.End();

            GL.PopMatrix();
        };
```

NSView側の設定かもしれませんが、どのような処理を追加すればいいかがわからない状況です。
以下の様なコードも試してみましたが、そうすると、GLの描画が消えてしまいました。

```
CALayer viewLayer = CALayer.Create ();
viewLayer.BackgroundColor = NSColor.Clear.CGColor;
renderView.WantsLayer = false;
renderView.Layer = viewLayer;
※renderViewが、GL描画を行っているNSViewです。
```

ご助言をいただきたいと思います。

Comment: もろもろ、調査した結果、CALayerを利用することで、解決しました。

Answer (score 1):

OpenTKというのは使ったことないですが、OpenGLで背景色を透明にする場合は glColorMask というのを設定してから glClearします。

通常の OpenGL での記述

```
glColorMask(true, true, true, true);  // Alphaも描画する設定
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glColorMask(true, true, true, false);  // 戻す
```

動くか分かりませんが、OpenTK ではこのように書くのでしょうか。GL.Clearの前後に１行ずつ足しました。

```
GL.ColorMask(true, true, true, true);  // Alphaも描画する設定
GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);
GL.ColorMask(true, true, true, false);  // 戻す
```